# Change selected icon color of bottom navigation color, based on App theme (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to change the colour of the selected icon in the bottom navigation bar. I already have a selector, that changes the colour of the selected icon. My problem is, that if the App theme changes, the colours won't change.

How can I change the selector colour, based on the App theme?

**This is the selector I already have:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/standardThemeAccentSelected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/standardThemeAccentNonSelected" />
</selector>
```

**Those are my themes/styles:**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="baseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/standardThemePrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/standardThemePrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/standardThemeAccentText</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/standardThemeAccentBackground</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/standardThemeAccentNonSelected</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/standardThemeAccentNonSelected</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/standardThemeAccentContent</item>
        <item name="drawableTint">@color/standardThemeAccentText</item>
        <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/baseThemeNav</item>
        <!--Navigation-->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/standardThemePrimaryColor</item>
    </style>
    <!--Base Theme Nav-->
    <style name="baseThemeNav" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/standardThemePrimaryColor</item>
    </style>

    <!--Black Theme-->
    <style name="blackTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blackThemePrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blackThemePrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blackThemeAccentText</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blackThemeAccentBackground</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/blackThemeAccentNonSelected</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/blackThemeAccentNonSelected</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blackThemeAccentContent</item>
        <item name="drawableTint">@color/blackThemeAccentNonSelected</item>
        <item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/blackThemeNav</item>
        <!--Navigation Style-->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/blackThemePrimaryColor</item>
    </style>
    <!--Black Theme nav-->
    <style name="blackThemeNav" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blackThemePrimaryColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Declare custom style attribute add it to your themes and reference it from within your selector.

Comment: And if I change the theme? Will the style referenced from the selector be the same?